# reload a PHP include or require

Tags: php, jquery

I am using JQuery tabs and i want to be able to load each page as it is clicked on.

so my index.php has an include at the top for my database connections etc, i then have these tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
```

and each tab has its own content div:

```
<div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">

                  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">

                  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
```

Then i have individual pages that do not include the database connection which i want to include in the tab content divs

but i dont want to have them all load when the index.php page loads. how can i set each include to load when the tab is clicked?

Comment: If I understand, you should use ajax calls to load the content when you click.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call ajax change of tab. You can use follwing code. This example is given in jQuery site

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find more details here https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 2):

You can use load function of jquery. And you can include php file onclick of your tab. Use below code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabid").click(function()
{
    $("#whereToPlace").load("http://path/to/file");
});
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to include Jquery library first

Answer (score 0):

when you click on tab try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tab_1').click(function(){
    //tab sub contents
$('.sub_content1').load(/*url if div with id then #tab_1_content*/);    
})
    $('#tab_2').click(function(){
    //tab sub contents
$('.sub_content2').load(/*url if div with id then #tab_2_content*/);    
})
 }
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not doing anything. I also tried adding an alert but that doesnt show either

Comment: i have tried this - http://jsfiddle.net/byzozq3b/ - this is redirecting the page however my application changes the active tab but does nothing else

Comment: how does this load other pages into the divs?